# Is the phrase ' the echo of our sentiment' natural in English?

Tags: collocations

I'm confused with the use of the phrase 'the echo of our sentiment' in the following sentence. Is it meaningful and natural in English?

> Poetry is the echo of our sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a usual thing to say, but it makes sense. It's about poetry, and it's a sort of poetic thing to say. The use of "echo" is a metaphor. Poetry expresses our feelings, and that expression is likened to an echo.